# want to display user list except specific one

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a user list where logged in users account will not placed. please suggest me any ideas to solve it, thank you for cooperation...

SQL query is placed below :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE level = 'student' 
      AND level NOT LIKE '%{$_SESSION['SESS_name']}%' 
ORDER BY level ASC
```

Comment: Your code is badly escaped. This will not work. The SQL expects the requested session variable to contain a level yet the parameter leads to believe it holds a name.

Comment: u should post some sample data. that would help a lot

Comment: what is `level`? Your query only contains one parameter in the query string: `level`. is it a user level or the username? so, what does `$_SESSION['SESS_name']` contain?

Comment: @sailingthoms,`level` contains user level and the `$_SESSION['SESS_name']` contains the username of the user account.

Comment: so there might be something wrong with this query because on one hand u select on `level = 'student'` but on the other hand u evaluate `level NOT LIKE '%{$_SESSION['SESS_name']}%'`. Are u sure it is right 2 time `level`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note you have an sql injection vulnerability. Try this

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE level = "student" AND id != :userId ORDER BY level ASC');
$stmt->execute([':userId' => $_SESSION['userId']]);
```

This is using PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Store your logged in user id in the session instead of the name

Answer (score 0):

I usually just create a column in my table calles `logged`, and then when they login, you just set this value to `1`, and when they logout you set to `0`.

THen to view all logged users its as simple as...

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE logged = 1;
```

And to view unlogged in users...

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE logged = 0;
```

Comment: Thas wouldn't work if it should only be the current used that is excluded from the list and not all users currently logged in.

Comment: Then shouldnt he just do WHERE username != $_SESSION['username'] or something to that effect?  I was just going off of his grammar, where he states..... user list where logged in users will not be placed....thats plural....

Comment: You are totally correct - I missed that in the original post.

Comment: thanx to all for sharing great ideas and suggestions... its solved, thanx guys...

Comment: It's plural because there can be multiple logged in users, and each of them is not shown to themselves.